# Animating text within a Tkinter Entry widget

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to develop a search bar in Tkinter using the Entry widget. So far, I've managed to insert centred text that moves to the left when the user clicks the Entry by binding the `<FocusIn>` event. The text then vanishes when the user begins typing and reappears when the Entry widget becomes empty.

The movement of the text from centre to left is done using the `justify` option. This means that the text sort of jumps from centre to left which isn't what I want. I want to find a way of animating the text so that it slides from the centre of the widget to the left of the widget smoothly.

Any help would be appreciated. I understand that this may be possible using a Tkinter canvas?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

class SearchEntry:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        self.entry = Entry(self.master, foreground = '#666', justify = 'center')
        self.entry.insert(0, 'Search')
        self.entry.bind('<FocusIn>', self.onfocus)
        self.entry.bind('<FocusOut>', self.outfocus)
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        if self.entry.get() == '':
            self.entry.insert(0, 'Search')
            self.entry.icursor(0)
            self.entry.bind('<Key>', self.keypress)
        self.master.after(1, self.update)

    def onfocus(self, event):
        if self.entry.get() == 'Search':
            self.entry.configure(justify = 'left')
            self.entry.icursor(0)
            self.entry.bind('<Key>', self.keypress)

    def outfocus(self, event):
        if self.entry.get() == 'Search':
            self.entry.configure(justify = 'center')

    def keypress(self, event):
        self.entry.delete(0, END)
        self.entry.unbind('<Key>')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing you can do without resorting to some sort of hack. For example, you could overlay a canvas on top of the entry and do the animation in the canvas. It will be tricky (though probably not impossible) to manage the focus in the case where the user immediately starts typing.

You could also use the `xview` command to slowly scroll the data, but that would involve inserting enough space characters to make the data scrollable.

Tkinter isn't like css where you can do interesting animations. It's simply not designed to work that way. Tkinter is not a comfortable minivan full of cupholders and dvd players, it's a pickup truck. Though, it's a pickup truck loaded with legos, so you can usually build what you want if you're willing to put in a lot of effort.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I think I'll try using a canvas then, maybe I can work something out.